# Why 'withContext' does not switch coroutines under 'runBlocking'?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to find out the executing order and thread switching of kotlin coroutines. I used `withContext` to switch to another context and run time consuming tasks, so the main thread won't be blocked. But kotlin did not switch context as expected.

Code runs on kotlin playground: https://pl.kotl.in/V0lbCU25K

Case that doesn't work

```
suspend fun main() = runBlocking {
    println("Hello, world!!!")
    println(Thread.currentThread().name)
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println("Before heavy load: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        println("After heavy load: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }
    println("waiting")
    println(Thread.currentThread().name)
}
```

Outputs

```
Hello, world!!!
main @coroutine#1
Before heavy load: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#1
After heavy load: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#1
waiting
main @coroutine#1
```

The `sleep` function in the above code blocks runs at the same thread  as main thread and blocks it.

---

Below cases match my expectation(Time consuming task does not block main thread)

Case 1

```
suspend fun main() = runBlocking {
    println("Hello, world!!!")
    println(Thread.currentThread().name)
    launch {
        println("Before heavy load: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        println("After heavy load: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }
    println("waiting")
    println(Thread.currentThread().name)
}
```

Outputs

```
Hello, world!!!
main @coroutine#1
waiting
main @coroutine#1
Before heavy load: main @coroutine#2
After heavy load: main @coroutine#2
```

Case 2

```
suspend fun main() = runBlocking {
    println("Hello, world!!!")
    println(Thread.currentThread().name)
    launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            println("Before heavy load: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            Thread.sleep(5000)
            println("After heavy load: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
    }
    println("waiting")
    println(Thread.currentThread().name)
}
```

Outputs

```
Hello, world!!!
main @coroutine#1
waiting
main @coroutine#1
Before heavy load: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#2
After heavy load: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#2
```

Comment: Why don't you use the suspend `sleep()` function instead of `Thread.sleep()`?

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv I tried the `suspend delay()` function, it still blocked the parent thread.

Comment: Your Case 1 does block the main thread. It just happens to do it after the rest of the code in the top-level coroutine has run. Your Case 2 can be shortened to `launch(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }`.

Answer (score 8):

> I used `withContext` to switch to another context and run time consuming tasks, so the main thread won't be blocked. But kotlin did not switch context as expected.

Your `withContext` call did indeed free up the main thread. It transferred the work to another thread, but at that point your main thread was left with nothing else to do but wait for the `withContext` invocation to complete. `runBlocking` starts an event loop that can serve any number of concurrent coroutines, but since you have only one, that one coroutine had to complete in order for the `runBlocking` block to complete.

Here's a demonstration of what it means that the thread isn't blocked:

```
fun main() {
    measureTimeMillis {
        runBlocking {
            launchManyCoroutines()
            println("Top-level coroutine sleeping on thread ${currentThread().name}")
            delay(2_000)
            println("Top-level coroutine done")
        }
    }.also { println("Program done in $it milliseconds") }

}

private fun CoroutineScope.launchManyCoroutines() {
    val cpuCount = getRuntime().availableProcessors()
    (1 until cpuCount).forEach { coroId ->
        launch { // on the main thread
            val sum = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                println("Coroutine #$coroId computing on thread ${currentThread().name}")
                computeResult()
            }
            println("Coroutine #$coroId done on thread ${currentThread().name}:" +
                    " sum = $sum")
        }
    }
    (cpuCount + 1..100).forEach { coroId ->
        launch { // on the main thread
            println("Coroutine $coroId sleeping 1 s on thread ${currentThread().name}")
            delay(1_000)
            println("Coroutine #$coroId done on thread ${currentThread().name}")
        }
    }
}

private fun computeResult(): Int {
    val rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current()
    return (1..1_000_000).map { rnd.nextInt() }.sum()
}
```

This program launches (100 + availableProcessors) concurrent coroutines, all on the main thread. Some of them use `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` to perform a CPU-intensive task (summing a million random integers) on a thread pool, while others perform suspending work (delay for one second) directly on the main thread. Finally, the top-level coroutine sleeps for 2 seconds before completing.

The entire program completes in just above 2 seconds and prints something like the following:

```
Top-level coroutine sleeping on thread main

Coroutine #2 computing on thread DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
Coroutine #3 computing on thread DefaultDispatcher-worker-3
Coroutine #4 computing on thread DefaultDispatcher-worker-5
Coroutine #1 computing on thread DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Coroutine #5 computing on thread DefaultDispatcher-worker-6
Coroutine #6 computing on thread DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
Coroutine #7 computing on thread DefaultDispatcher-worker-8

Coroutine 9 sleeping 1 s on thread main
Coroutine 10 sleeping 1 s on thread main
...
Coroutine 99 sleeping 1 s on thread main
Coroutine 100 sleeping 1 s on thread main

Coroutine #3 done on thread main: sum = -1248358970
Coroutine #4 done on thread main: sum = -228252033
Coroutine #6 done on thread main: sum = -147126590
Coroutine #2 done on thread main: sum = -1065374439
Coroutine #1 done on thread main: sum = -2029316381
Coroutine #7 done on thread main: sum = -865387844
Coroutine #5 done on thread main: sum = -1695642504

Coroutine #9 done on thread main
Coroutine #10 done on thread main
...
Coroutine #99 done on thread main
Coroutine #100 done on thread main

Top-level coroutine done
Program done in 2066 milliseconds
```

Note than everything the program does, happens while the main coroutine is sleeping on the main thread.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between `withContext` and `runBlocking`. Both wait for the result while being suspended, allowing other work to be done on the current thread somewhere else, no?

Comment: No, `runBlocking` is a plain, non-suspendable function that blocks, and while blocking actually executes the machinery needed to call suspendable functions.

Comment: I see. So actually `runBlocking` can help in case I want to have strict ordering, not allowing to go to other tasks using this thread, right? I ask this because I want to solve this problem: https://www.reddit.com/r/android_devs/comments/w4fnbj/need_some_tips_about_reducing_anr_by_switching_to/ . If I have a Dispatcher that uses a single-thread-pool, every call to `runInterruptible(backgroundWorkDispatcher)` will create a new job that will be added to the queue and will be launched only after the others will finish, right?

Comment: If you don't mind blocking your thread and you are forced to access some logic that's trapped inside suspendable functions, `runBlocking` is a good approach.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**

Use `launch`

`withContext` doesn't do async. It merges the contexts. To do an async job use the **launch** function with the specified coroutine context.

---

`withContext` does not actually run async, it merges the contexts.

According to the [Kotlin core docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html):

`withContext`:

> Calls the specified suspending block with a given coroutine context, suspends until it completes, and returns the result.

So the expected result of this code using `withContext`:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
        println("Before block ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            println("Long op ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            delay(1000)
        }
        println("After block")
    }
```

is:

```
Before block main @coroutine#1
Long op DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#1
After block
```

What you want can be achieved using `launch` function inside your coroutine:

The result of the below code:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
        println("Before block ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            println("Long op ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            delay(1000)
        }
        println("After block")
    }
```

will be:

```
Before block main @coroutine#1
After block
Long op DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#2
```

Comment: I get a different result for your first example: https://pl.kotl.in/Ee7dN0rPp. For me, withContext does indeed switch threads (from main to a DefaultDispatch-worker). I think @MarkoTopolnik's answer does a better job of explaining how withContext can indeed switch threads, but the unless you do a launch or async everything is still synchronous, so runblocking will just wait for the withContext block to complete.